# How to catch NoReverseMatch with phantomjs browser testing

Tags: django-templates, tdd, browser-testing

I try to apply TDD in my project. I have this template:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Selamat datang di Infoplace</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Selamat datang di InfoPlace</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'registration_page' %}" id="registration_link">Daftar</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't have url named 'registration_page' yet. When I open this page in browser, I got error **NoReverseMatch**, obviously. But how do I catch this error with a headless browser testing? Or at least display the stacktrace of **NoReverseMatch** in the test result.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can use django's built-in  TestCase & Client to catch this problem. All I have to do is create a test that request to the url/view that render this template. Than the NoReverseMatch error will be displayed.